# Some of my NSStrings are alphanumeric. How do I tell which ones contain numbers and which ones don't?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad

```
NSString *test = @"example";

NSString *test2 = @"ex12am243ple";
```

Is there any easy way to determine which string contains a number in it (0-9) and which one doesn't?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if([testString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSetOfNumbers].location == NSNotFound)
{
//there are no numbers in this string
}
else
{
//there is at least 1 number in this string
}
```

p.s. you can look at the docs of `NSCharacterSet` for the available ones, but the one you probably want is `decimalDigitCharacterSet` so you would use `[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]` in place of "characterSetOfNumbers" in the above code.

Comment: You should probably add how to get the characterSet... Good answer though!

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([test isMatchedByRegEx:@"\d+"]) {
   // string contains numbers
}
```

EDIT: also worth noting that you need to import `regex.h`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Jesse's code, it is definitely easier to put it into a category.

```
@interface NSString (Numeric)
- (BOOL) isNumeric;
@end

@implementation NSString (numeric)
- (BOOL) isNumeric {
    NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
    return ([self rangeOfCharactersFromSet:numbers].location == NSNotFound ? YES : NO);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to test for numbers. Here is an example but you may need to change it for your needs.

```
- (BOOL)stringContainsNumbers:(NSString *)string {
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[0-9]" options:0 error:NULL];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    return  numberOfMatches > 0;
}
```